# CS background-image produces Moiré effect

Tags: css, math, graphics, raster

I created a 2x2 chequerboard PNG image, shown here magnified in Gimp

[image]

And filled a blank web page with it

```
<style>html{background-image:url("/tmp/x.png");}</style>
```

The result was an unexpected Moiré pattern

[image]

Why does this happen?

Also why does this produce that triangle near the centre?

Comment: Please add the relevant code reproducing the issue

Comment: It's already on there

Comment: All you provided is images and basic css which should work, It'll just be a guessing game, And my guess is your image is `1px`x`1px` and by default backgrounds are repeated `background-repeat:repeat;` that's why you see that

Comment: The image is 2x2 and if it was 1x1 we would see a uniform solid colour. The image and CSS is *all there is*, there is no other code to post. What else were you expecting?

Comment: Yes a 2x2 that's what i meant, I'm expecting a working code example that anybody can just copy paste and see exactly what you're seeing, I'm expecting more information about your setup, Because as i said it should work fine, but it doesn't so obviously there's something wrong, The fact that this question isn't receiving much attention proves my point.